# Async with mongodb and not updating properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, shopify

I have made a custom app for our company that i have stored barcodes inside a database.

Then each time a product that doesn't have a barcode gets it from the database and assigns it to the product.

The problem is that with a single product i don't have a problem but with multiples.

If i make a product with variants on shopify i get them all at the same time and it gets the same barcode for all variants.

I have made in mongodb objects that have 2 values , Barcode : 32112312 and Used : 'false' by default. When a barcode gets used i assign that value to true.

Thing is when i get 5 values at the sametime used field doesn't get updated as fast so it gives all the variants the same barcode.

I tried with sleep or timeout but does the same.

Here is my code ,

```
async.forEach(product.variants,(variant,callback) =>{
                            if(variant.barcode == ''){
                                    // console.log(variant.id);
                                
                                brd.find({used:"false"})
                                .sort({_id: 1})
                                .limit(1)
                                .then(barcode =>{

                                    shopify.productVariant
                                                    .update(variant.id ,({ barcode : barcode[0].barcode }))
                                                    .then((productresult)=> {console.log('To '+productresult.sku +' έχει '+productresult.barcode);
                                                                        
                                                            
                                                        },  (err)=> console.error(err));
                                                        brd.updateOne({_id:barcode[0].id},{used:"true"})
                                                        .then(barcodeupdate=>{
                                                            console.log('barcode added ');
                                                            
                                                            })  
                                                                               
                                                        callback();      
                                });     
                                
                                
                                
                               }
                               
                         });
```

console.log is like this

barcode added
barcode added
barcode added
barcode added
To 55095 έχει 1234546546547
To 55096 έχει 1234546546547
To 55098 έχει 1234546546547
To 55097 έχει 1234546546547

where i want something like this

To 55095 έχει 1234546546547
barcode added
To 55096 έχει 1234546546548
barcode added
To 55098 έχει 1234546546549
barcode added
To 55097 έχει 1234546546550
barcode added

Where i want something like this

Comment: What is your desired behavior, in words?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Your question is missing an English language description of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Ok. Problem is that i want to find a barcode that is not used from database assign it to a product and mark that as used. It's no problem with one product. The problem is when 2 or more products are sent to my programm so every product gets the same barcode.

Answer (score 0):

At the end i found the answer!

i made an async function that returns a single barcode and then i assign it to the product that doesn't have a barcode.

```
async function getbarcode(barcodenew){

                                 return brd.findOneAndUpdate({used: barcodenew},{used:"true"}).then(barcodeone => {return barcodeone});
                                     };


                             barcodeassigned = getbarcode("false");
                             barcodeassigned.then(function(result){

                                shopify.productVariant
                                .update(variant.id,({barcode: result.barcode}))
                                .then((productresult)=>console.log('To '+productresult.sku +' πήρε το barcode '+productresult.barcode),
                                (err)=> console.error(err));
                             })

``
```